# continuity of a two variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$u(x,y)={{x^{4/3}y^{5/3}}\over x^2+y^2}, u(0,0)=0$, could anyone help me whether

$1.$ u is continuous at $(0,0)$?

$2.$ find all points where $u_x$ exists.

$3.$ Is $u_x$ continous at $(0,0)$

$4.$ is $u$ differentiable a4 $(0,0)$?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: First, you can certainly calculate $u_x$, right? Post the answer as a comment.

Comment: This doesn't show a lot of homework... The technique is almost invariably the same. Write y=mx where m=m(x,y) is variable and study the behaviour in function of m and x. Answers 1. yes, 2. (x>=0,y>=0)-(0,0), 3. no, 4. no